# ZendFramework - How to create optgroup and there option using view helpers?

Tags: php, zend-framework, zend-form

How do i create this with $this->formSelect() ?

```
<select multiple>
    <optgroup label="a">
       <option>1</option> 
       <option>2</option>
    </optgroup>
    <optgroup label="b">
       <option>1</option> 
    </optgroup>
</select>
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

For the Zend_Form_Element_Select() it goes like this

```
$multiOptions = array(
  'Group A' => array(1 => 'First Value',2 => 'Second Value A),
  'Group B' => array(3 => 'Third Value'),
);

$element->setMultiOptions($multiOptions);
```

Note that you also have addMultiOption($option,$value) and addMultiOptions($options). Simply include the value or options in an additional array.

Comment: How can i have `Group A` also a ID? like 001

Comment: #Google Not sure what you mean with ID. An `optgroup` is not a item you can select. In Zend the key for an array `Group A` becomes a label and the label looks like a title in the  drop down menu. See [W3Schools](http://www.w3schools.com/html5/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml5_optgroup)

Comment: I am interested in the question being answered using XML, as it was requested, which would be useful with Zend_Config_XML and Zend_Form_Element

Comment: Please note that `setMultiOptions()` no longer exists in Zend Framework 3. Use [Mr Coder's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19330145/1155833) instead.

Answer (score 13):

In Zend Framework 2 this can be done as follows:

```
$this->add(array(
        'name'=>'Test',
        'type'=>'Zend\Form\Element\Select',
        'attributes'=>array('type'=>'select','required'=>'required'),
        'options'=>array(
            'label'=>'Test',
            'value_options'=>array('fruits'=>array('label'=>'Fruits','options'=>array('1'=>'Apple','2'=>'Mango')),'animals'=>array('label'=>'Animals','options'=>array('cat'=>'CAT','dog'=>'DOG'))),
            'empty_option'=>'Please Select'
        ),

    ));
```

please note that an option named empty_options doesn't exist instead empty_option should be used.

Comment: @DrCord I don't think you should have accepted the suggested edit - it should have been a comment.

Comment: maybe part of could have been a comment but the edit to the actual code that makes it working for users to copy paste as they are prone to do was a worthwhile edit.

Comment: @DrCord Even so, the first sentence shouldn't be here.

Comment: I moved it to the end. I don't agree it should be removed, how does it hurt the answer? if the answer that was here was only a typo then this won't help anyone but if it was because of a bad piece of code somewhere out there that users are using to tutorial from or something then this will certainly help many people...