# Option groups select in Zend Form

Tags: zend-framework, select, zend-form, optgroup

How do I get optiongroups in a dropdown select list where the optiongroups and options are in my database?

I have this in my db:

id | categorie | subcategorie 
1     apples      granny smith
2     apples      fiji
3     bananas     chiquita

and want to have a dropdown select like:

apples

- granny smith
- fiji

bananas

- chiquita

In my controller I get the array of the rows from the db. I have an array 
$arrSelectSubcategory and $arrSelectCategory. 
Answers I found suggest to use a multidimensional array so I tried to pass to the form a 2 dimensional array:

```
->addMultiOptions($arrSelectCategory->($arrSelectSubcategory));
```

but this does not work. Answers I found like [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9402026/zendframework-how-to-create-optgroup-and-there-option-using-view-helpers) only deal with predefined option groups where I get them from my db.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Imagine that your values ​​in an array like this one:

```
$fruits = array('apples'=>array('id_granny_smith'=>'granny smith', 
                                'id_fiji'=>'fiji'), 
                'bananas' => array('id_chiquita'=>'chiquita')
               );
```

You can try something like this:

```
$fruits_select = new  Zend_Form_Element_Select('fruits', array('escape' => false));
foreach($fruits as $fruit => $name_fruit){
    $fruits_select->addMultiOptions(array($fruit=>array()));
    foreach($name_fruit as $key => $val){
            $fruits_select ->addMultiOption($key, $val);
    }
}
```

The result is:

```
<select name="fruits" id="fruits">
    <optgroup label="apples">
    </optgroup>
    <option value="id_granny_smith" label="granny smith">granny smith</option>
    <option value="id_fiji" label="fiji">fiji</option>
    <optgroup label="bananas">
    </optgroup>
    <option value="id_chiquita" label="chiquita">chiquita</option>
</select>
```

---

with your comment, your array is like this:

```
$fruits_bdd = array('0' => array('id' => 1, 'category' => 'apples', 'subcategorie'=> 'granny smith'),
                    '1' => array('id' => 2, 'category' => 'apples', 'subcategorie'=> 'fiji'),
                    '2' => array('id' => 3, 'category' => 'bananas', 'subcategorie'=> 'chiquita'),
);
```

So to have the array `$fruits` like my answer, do that:

```
$fruits = array();  
foreach($fruits_bdd as $fruit_bdd){
        $fruits[$fruit_bdd['category']][$fruit_bdd['id']] =$fruit_bdd['subcategorie'];
}
```

Comment: I need to get the 'apples' and 'bananas' in $fruits from my array categorie. How do I manage that?

Comment: @zef: how is your array categorie?

Comment: The array I get from my db is: Array([0] => Array ([id]=>1, [category]=>apples, [subcategorie]=>granny smith) , [1] => Array ([id]=>2, [category]=>apples, [subcategorie]=>fiji) , [2] => Array ([id]=>3, [category]=>bananas, [subcategorie]=>chiquita)

Comment: The $fruits array contains only the first subcategorie from each categorie; Apple -> Granny Smith is in the Array but Apple -> Fiji is not. Wait... let me check again...